# Scrapy ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure was not found

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, importerror

I'm trying to create a scrapy project but everytime I try `scrapy startproject tutorial` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python 3.6\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python 3.6\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python 3.6\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "c:\python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "c:\python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "c:\python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 11, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "c:\python 3.6\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure was not found.
```

I'm on Windows 10 and lxml version is `3.8.0`

### EDIT

after installing the unofficial build(`lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`) from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) it works.

Comment: Thanks. When visiting the site I saw there was a version 4.0 of lxml, lxml‑4.0.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl. So, I thought "new version, I'l have that one", installed it and still got the error. I then installed the version you mentioned (lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl) that works like a charm. I have no idea what the situation is for 64-bit Python, your miles may vary.